# how to use counter in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sir,

I'm making a pedometer application using the accelerometer feature of the iPhone.

I just want to detect the steps while walking using some counter.

Should I use a loop to get the updated X,Y,Z coordinates?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You may wish to refer to this question, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984003/how-to-implement-pedometer-in-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Look into using callback functions.  Here's an example: http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/accelerometer-101.html