# Pedometer App for a phone

Tags: iphone, android

Where could someone get the code or guidelines to create a universal pedometer app for various phones?
 or would you have to create a different app for each phone?
 or could you just create an app for android & iphone?

How would a coder go about doing the task? where to look for help?

Comment: pedometer or pedo-meter?

Comment: Where would a coder get code?  They'd write it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement pedometer in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984003/how-to-implement-pedometer-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Titanium Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/) is a cross-platform dev environment that lets you write apps in javascript that are then compiled into native apps for iPhone/iPad and Android.  I haven't used it myself, but I've heard that it does not completely suck.  I do not know whether it supports the accelerometers in these devices (which would be necessary for a pedometer app), but it probably does.

However, since you'd have to learn a bunch of new stuff just to use Titanium, it might make more sense to just pick a platform and spend your time learning to program it natively (Android has more marketshare now - maybe - so I'd recommend just learning that; Android is much easier to work with than iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Mobile does support Accelerometer.

For iPhone, there is an offical library in the framework that will detect steps, but it will only work from iOS7.
Look here: [/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMStepCounter_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013504)

Please be aware there are restrictions for what kind of Apps can run in the background on an iPhone.